# how to setChecked radio button in programmatically (radio button created in dynamically ) android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I try that

`radioButton.setChecked(true);`

but its only work 4th radio button. I try to create radio button dynamically. I create radio buttion within for loop, then store the radio button value. Then restore the radio button value (that means, I have 4 options that time I choose 2nd option and saved it then restore it(setChecked 2nd option) ) but its only setChecked 4th option.

Create radioButton.

```
for (int k = 0; k < choiceElementList.size(); k++) {
  if (choiceElementList.get(k).dataFormatId == 1) {
    radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
    radioButton.setText(choiceElementList.get(k).getDataFormatValue());
    radioButton.setLayoutParams(params1);
    radioButton.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    Log.e("setid", String.valueOf(choiceElementList.get(k).getId())) ;
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
  } 
}
```

Try to restore that

```
if(choiceElementList.get(k).getId() == Cons.Id){
  radioButton.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: yes ,correct. i add  id  into ArrayList<Integer>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set Ids to your `RadioButtons`

```
for (int k = 0; k < choiceElementList.size(); k++) {

    if (choiceElementList.get(k).dataFormatId == 1) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());

        // Set ID to Radio Button
        radioButton.setId(k);

        radioButton.setText(choiceElementList.get(k).getDataFormatValue());
        radioButton.setLayoutParams(params1);
        radioButton.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
        Log.e("setid", String.valueOf(choiceElementList.get(k).getId())) ;
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    } 
}
```

now just use your `RadioGroup` to check desire `RadioButton` with its ID

```
if(choiceElementList.get(k).getId() == Cons.Id){
    radioGroup.check(k);   // K will be your ID Set for your desire RadioButton
}
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

according to this code segments, your `radioButton` variable only refer last created element (radiobutton). That's why it only marks fourth one. You need to get correct reference for radio button what u want.

Comment: I got the correct reference (id). But its only marks last one.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're adding all your RadioButton in a RadioGroup. When a RadioButton is checked in a RadioGroup, the othe RadioButton will be unchecked. You can see the [RadioGroup documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup) say it clearly:

> This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of radio buttons. Checking one radio button that belongs to a radio group unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.
>
> Intially, all of the radio buttons are unchecked. While it is not possible to uncheck a particular radio button, the radio group can be cleared to remove the checked state.
>
> The selection is identified by the unique id of the radio button as defined in the XML layout file.